# What is the @import for compass's image_url?

Tags: compass-sass, compass

Our designer uses `@import 'compass';` everywhere. Our asset compilation times are too high to deploy to Heroku. I'm trying to replace these with the specific paths for only the bits we use, for example `@import 'compass/css3/border-radius';`

What is the include path for `image_url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image_url` is compass native function. Meaning there isn't Sass partial for it but output is computed using Ruby magic and information passed in compass configuration.